# RestBody, creating Json Payload in C# causes conflict because a Key is a c# keyword

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I am using RestSharp to create a RestRequest
It seems pretty simple and straight forward.

The issue i noticed though is that when developing the object that will be a part of the body of the payload, a key, is called "params".

If you didnt know.  Params is a keyword.  How do i create a payload to properly implement, despite the fact a key could be special for the C# language?

```
var payload = new {
    data = "",
    command = new {
        name = "Foo",
        params = "Bar"
    }
};
RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.POST);
request.Resource = "";
request.AddBody(payload);
var result = Client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: There's no JSON payload in the code. It's the anonymous type definition that complains

Comment: I was following other examples online, and i agree, it isnt json perse, it will be parsed as such in the body

Comment: This isn't about JSON. This is the [object initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) used to create an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). `payload` is just an object that `AddBody` may or may not serialize into a JSON string. The problem is that the property named `params` has the same name as a C# keyword. You'd have the same problem if you called it `int` or `DateTime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just put `@` before *params* :

```
var payload = new {
    data = "",
    command = new {
        name = "Foo",
        @params = "Bar"
    }
};
```

I've tested it and the outputted JSON  will be `params` without the `@`.